# Blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cors

> Error:Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 API cors config:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy,
                       builder =>
                       {    builder
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                   .WithOrigins("https://www.hotff.com",
   "https://www.hotff.com:44389","https://localhost:4200",
   "http://localhost:4200","https://localhost:44371",
   "http://localhost:4300","http://127.0.0.1:8080") //.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               
                                   .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                                   .AllowCredentials();
                       }));
```

This config works from  Angular 8 client, no issue on port http://localhost

When the API is deployed on an IIS 10 server the request works from an Edge browser fine but not from Android or Chrome browsers. Tried all solutions I could find, read everything I could find.

I think the issue is the pre-flight request...

Comment: I had to resort to the client proxy method to fix this not ideal but works
{
    "/myAPI/*": {
        "target": "http://www.hotff.com:44389",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

Comment: I would like a server side fix if possible.

Comment: The problem is slightly different, but the explanation and solution are the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70061406/why-delete-request-blocked-by-cors-policy-on-asp-net-core-3-1-after-project-publ/70065324#70065324