# Why DELETE request blocked by CORS policy on ASP.NET Core 3.1 after project published to IIS?

Tags: cors, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular 9 project for fornt-end. actually it was working but then I added some NPM packages to my angular project "ngx-saveAs" and "saveAS" but Im not sure that this is a related reason. any ideas that helps me find it is appreciated ?
here is my startup :

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200",
                                    "https://localhost:4200",
                                    "http://192.168.10.82",
                                    "http://192.168.10.82:4200",
                                    "https://192.168.10.82",
                                    "https://192.168.10.82:4200",
                                    "192.168.10.82",
                                    "192.168.10.82:4200",
                                    "192.168.10.164",
                                    "192.168.10.163",
                                    "http://192.168.10.163:64534",
                                    "http://192.168.10.163:64535",
                                    "http://192.168.10.164",
                                    "http://192.168.10.164/",
                                    "https://192.168.10.164",
                                    "http://192.168.10.164:4200",
                                    "http://192.168.10.164:4200/",
                                    "https://192.168.10.164:4200",
                                    "http://192.168.10.163:64534/",
                                    "http://192.168.10.163:64535/"
                    ).WithMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT")
                    .AllowAnyMethod().WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination")
                    .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
             
            }));
```

and error is  :
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.10.163:64535/api/v1/Formula/24' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

and : `DELETE http://192.168.10.163:64535/api/v1/Formula/24 net::ERR_FAILED`

and :

```
ERROR 
Error: خطا در برقراری ارتباط با سرور at ApiErrorHandlerService.handleError (http://localhost:4200/main.js:10307:27) at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.js:10400:177) at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:285330:31) at FilterSubscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:282590:26) at FilterSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:282570:18) at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems

There are two main problems with your CORS configuration:

1. You're calling `WithMethods` and then `AllowAnyMethod`. As evident from [the aspnetcore source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs#L178), the latter cancels the former and results in an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *` header in responses to preflight requests. However, [the asterisk (`*`) in that header only works as a wildcard for non-credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods#directives). And your server expects credentialed requests because you're also calling `AllowCredentials`.
2. You're calling `AllowAnyHeader`. This [results](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs#L189) in an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` header in responses to preflight requests. However, again (same as in 1.), [the asterisk (`*`) in that header only works as a wildcard for non-credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#directives).

All this is clearly explained on [MDN's page on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards), which you should take the time to read carefully.

### Solution

If you call `AllowCredentials`, you cannot call `AllowAnyHeader` or `AllowAnyMethod` (or `AllowAnyOrigin`). You have to specify the allowed methods and headers explicitly. Something like this:

```cs
builder
  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
  .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT")
  .WithHeaders() // <--- list the allowed headers here
  .AllowCredentials()
  .WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination");
```